# Spring data r2dbc - Composite Primary key

Tags: mysql, spring-data-r2dbc

Looks like Spring Data r2dbc does not support composite primary key. Is that a known issue?

I dont see support for @Embedded.

Comment: I am wondering that this question does not have thousands of views and tens of upvotes! :) Isn't it something which a big amount of people need and are waiting for?

Answer (score 5):

This is not yet supported in R2DBC.

The [Support for Composite Keys using @Embeded and @Id #574](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/574) issue in Spring Data is open since 04 April 2019, which has been already 5 years (as of March 2024).

Comment: The issue was opened on 2019-Apr-04, more than 2 years ago :(